# aplay не воспроизводит звук когда указываю девайс воспроизведения

Tags: linux, alsa

При воспроизведении файла через `aplay` встретился с ошибкой, если указавать устройство, на котором воспроизводить

```
aplay -D hw:1,0 test2.wav 
Playing WAVE 'test2.wav' : Float 32 bit Little Endian, Rate 44100 Hz, Stereo
aplay: set_params:1343: Sample format non available
Available formats:
- S16_LE
- S24_3LE
```

Если же воспроизводить без указания устройства или указании устройства `default`, то все работает на той же звуковой карте

`aplay -lL`

```
default
    Playback/recording through the PulseAudio sound server
surround21
    2.1 Surround output to Front and Subwoofer speakers
surround40
    4.0 Surround output to Front and Rear speakers
surround41
    4.1 Surround output to Front, Rear and Subwoofer speakers
surround50
    5.0 Surround output to Front, Center and Rear speakers
surround51
    5.1 Surround output to Front, Center, Rear and Subwoofer speakers
surround71
    7.1 Surround output to Front, Center, Side, Rear and Woofer speakers
null
    Discard all samples (playback) or generate zero samples (capture)
samplerate
    Rate Converter Plugin Using Samplerate Library
speexrate
    Rate Converter Plugin Using Speex Resampler
jack
    JACK Audio Connection Kit
oss
    Open Sound System
pulse
    PulseAudio Sound Server
upmix
    Plugin for channel upmix (4,6,8)
vdownmix
    Plugin for channel downmix (stereo) with a simple spacialization
sysdefault:CARD=PCH
    HDA Intel PCH, ALC887-VD Analog
    Default Audio Device
front:CARD=PCH,DEV=0
    HDA Intel PCH, ALC887-VD Analog
    Front speakers
surround21:CARD=PCH,DEV=0
    HDA Intel PCH, ALC887-VD Analog
    2.1 Surround output to Front and Subwoofer speakers
surround40:CARD=PCH,DEV=0
    HDA Intel PCH, ALC887-VD Analog
    4.0 Surround output to Front and Rear speakers
surround41:CARD=PCH,DEV=0
    HDA Intel PCH, ALC887-VD Analog
    4.1 Surround output to Front, Rear and Subwoofer speakers
surround50:CARD=PCH,DEV=0
    HDA Intel PCH, ALC887-VD Analog
    5.0 Surround output to Front, Center and Rear speakers
surround51:CARD=PCH,DEV=0
    HDA Intel PCH, ALC887-VD Analog
    5.1 Surround output to Front, Center, Rear and Subwoofer speakers
surround71:CARD=PCH,DEV=0
    HDA Intel PCH, ALC887-VD Analog
    7.1 Surround output to Front, Center, Side, Rear and Woofer speakers
iec958:CARD=PCH,DEV=0
    HDA Intel PCH, ALC887-VD Digital
    IEC958 (S/PDIF) Digital Audio Output
hdmi:CARD=PCH,DEV=0
    HDA Intel PCH, HDMI 0
    HDMI Audio Output
hdmi:CARD=PCH,DEV=1
    HDA Intel PCH, HDMI 1
    HDMI Audio Output
hdmi:CARD=PCH,DEV=2
    HDA Intel PCH, HDMI 2
    HDMI Audio Output
hdmi:CARD=PCH,DEV=3
    HDA Intel PCH, HDMI 3
    HDMI Audio Output
hdmi:CARD=PCH,DEV=4
    HDA Intel PCH, HDMI 4
    HDMI Audio Output
dmix:CARD=PCH,DEV=0
    HDA Intel PCH, ALC887-VD Analog
    Direct sample mixing device
dmix:CARD=PCH,DEV=1
    HDA Intel PCH, ALC887-VD Digital
    Direct sample mixing device
dmix:CARD=PCH,DEV=3
    HDA Intel PCH, HDMI 0
    Direct sample mixing device
dmix:CARD=PCH,DEV=7
    HDA Intel PCH, HDMI 1
    Direct sample mixing device
dmix:CARD=PCH,DEV=8
    HDA Intel PCH, HDMI 2
    Direct sample mixing device
dmix:CARD=PCH,DEV=9
    HDA Intel PCH, HDMI 3
    Direct sample mixing device
dmix:CARD=PCH,DEV=10
    HDA Intel PCH, HDMI 4
    Direct sample mixing device
dsnoop:CARD=PCH,DEV=0
    HDA Intel PCH, ALC887-VD Analog
    Direct sample snooping device
dsnoop:CARD=PCH,DEV=1
    HDA Intel PCH, ALC887-VD Digital
    Direct sample snooping device
dsnoop:CARD=PCH,DEV=3
    HDA Intel PCH, HDMI 0
    Direct sample snooping device
dsnoop:CARD=PCH,DEV=7
    HDA Intel PCH, HDMI 1
    Direct sample snooping device
dsnoop:CARD=PCH,DEV=8
    HDA Intel PCH, HDMI 2
    Direct sample snooping device
dsnoop:CARD=PCH,DEV=9
    HDA Intel PCH, HDMI 3
    Direct sample snooping device
dsnoop:CARD=PCH,DEV=10
    HDA Intel PCH, HDMI 4
    Direct sample snooping device
hw:CARD=PCH,DEV=0
    HDA Intel PCH, ALC887-VD Analog
    Direct hardware device without any conversions
hw:CARD=PCH,DEV=1
    HDA Intel PCH, ALC887-VD Digital
    Direct hardware device without any conversions
hw:CARD=PCH,DEV=3
    HDA Intel PCH, HDMI 0
    Direct hardware device without any conversions
hw:CARD=PCH,DEV=7
    HDA Intel PCH, HDMI 1
    Direct hardware device without any conversions
hw:CARD=PCH,DEV=8
    HDA Intel PCH, HDMI 2
    Direct hardware device without any conversions
hw:CARD=PCH,DEV=9
    HDA Intel PCH, HDMI 3
    Direct hardware device without any conversions
hw:CARD=PCH,DEV=10
    HDA Intel PCH, HDMI 4
    Direct hardware device without any conversions
plughw:CARD=PCH,DEV=0
    HDA Intel PCH, ALC887-VD Analog
    Hardware device with all software conversions
plughw:CARD=PCH,DEV=1
    HDA Intel PCH, ALC887-VD Digital
    Hardware device with all software conversions
plughw:CARD=PCH,DEV=3
    HDA Intel PCH, HDMI 0
    Hardware device with all software conversions
plughw:CARD=PCH,DEV=7
    HDA Intel PCH, HDMI 1
    Hardware device with all software conversions
plughw:CARD=PCH,DEV=8
    HDA Intel PCH, HDMI 2
    Hardware device with all software conversions
plughw:CARD=PCH,DEV=9
    HDA Intel PCH, HDMI 3
    Hardware device with all software conversions
plughw:CARD=PCH,DEV=10
    HDA Intel PCH, HDMI 4
    Hardware device with all software conversions
usbstream:CARD=PCH
    HDA Intel PCH
    USB Stream Output
sysdefault:CARD=SoundCard
    Xonar SoundCard, USB Audio
    Default Audio Device
front:CARD=SoundCard,DEV=0
    Xonar SoundCard, USB Audio
    Front speakers
surround21:CARD=SoundCard,DEV=0
    Xonar SoundCard, USB Audio
    2.1 Surround output to Front and Subwoofer speakers
surround40:CARD=SoundCard,DEV=0
    Xonar SoundCard, USB Audio
    4.0 Surround output to Front and Rear speakers
surround41:CARD=SoundCard,DEV=0
    Xonar SoundCard, USB Audio
    4.1 Surround output to Front, Rear and Subwoofer speakers
surround50:CARD=SoundCard,DEV=0
    Xonar SoundCard, USB Audio
    5.0 Surround output to Front, Center and Rear speakers
surround51:CARD=SoundCard,DEV=0
    Xonar SoundCard, USB Audio
    5.1 Surround output to Front, Center, Rear and Subwoofer speakers
surround71:CARD=SoundCard,DEV=0
    Xonar SoundCard, USB Audio
    7.1 Surround output to Front, Center, Side, Rear and Woofer speakers
iec958:CARD=SoundCard,DEV=0
    Xonar SoundCard, USB Audio
    IEC958 (S/PDIF) Digital Audio Output
dmix:CARD=SoundCard,DEV=0
    Xonar SoundCard, USB Audio
    Direct sample mixing device
dmix:CARD=SoundCard,DEV=1
    Xonar SoundCard, USB Audio #1
    Direct sample mixing device
dmix:CARD=SoundCard,DEV=2
    Xonar SoundCard, USB Audio #2
    Direct sample mixing device
dmix:CARD=SoundCard,DEV=3
    Xonar SoundCard, USB Audio #3
    Direct sample mixing device
dsnoop:CARD=SoundCard,DEV=0
    Xonar SoundCard, USB Audio
    Direct sample snooping device
dsnoop:CARD=SoundCard,DEV=1
    Xonar SoundCard, USB Audio #1
    Direct sample snooping device
dsnoop:CARD=SoundCard,DEV=2
    Xonar SoundCard, USB Audio #2
    Direct sample snooping device
dsnoop:CARD=SoundCard,DEV=3
    Xonar SoundCard, USB Audio #3
    Direct sample snooping device
hw:CARD=SoundCard,DEV=0
    Xonar SoundCard, USB Audio
    Direct hardware device without any conversions
hw:CARD=SoundCard,DEV=1
    Xonar SoundCard, USB Audio #1
    Direct hardware device without any conversions
hw:CARD=SoundCard,DEV=2
    Xonar SoundCard, USB Audio #2
    Direct hardware device without any conversions
hw:CARD=SoundCard,DEV=3
    Xonar SoundCard, USB Audio #3
    Direct hardware device without any conversions
plughw:CARD=SoundCard,DEV=0
    Xonar SoundCard, USB Audio
    Hardware device with all software conversions
plughw:CARD=SoundCard,DEV=1
    Xonar SoundCard, USB Audio #1
    Hardware device with all software conversions
plughw:CARD=SoundCard,DEV=2
    Xonar SoundCard, USB Audio #2
    Hardware device with all software conversions
plughw:CARD=SoundCard,DEV=3
    Xonar SoundCard, USB Audio #3
    Hardware device with all software conversions
usbstream:CARD=SoundCard
    Xonar SoundCard
    USB Stream Output
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 0: ALC887-VD Analog [ALC887-VD Analog]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 1: ALC887-VD Digital [ALC887-VD Digital]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 7: HDMI 1 [HDMI 1]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 8: HDMI 2 [HDMI 2]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 9: HDMI 3 [HDMI 3]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 10: HDMI 4 [HDMI 4]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: SoundCard [Xonar SoundCard], device 0: USB Audio [USB Audio]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: SoundCard [Xonar SoundCard], device 1: USB Audio [USB Audio #1]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: SoundCard [Xonar SoundCard], device 2: USB Audio [USB Audio #2]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: SoundCard [Xonar SoundCard], device 3: USB Audio [USB Audio #3]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

Comment: ты уверен, что `hw:1,0` — это устройство по умолчанию («та же звуковая карта»)? `aplay -lL` в студию...

Comment: добавил в вопрос

Comment: по умолчанию/без параметров звук у тебя вообще идёт через `pulseaudio`... а `hw`, как написано выше — это прямой вывод без какой-либо конвертации... соответственно он доступен только в форматах, которые аппаратно поддерживает устройство... можешь использовать `plughw`, чтобы он конвертировать формат программно... что-то окромя очевидных фактов я сказать вряд ли смогу т.к. не настолько искушён в деталях конфигурации/устройства alsa...

Comment: Скорее всего частота по-умолчанию в alsa 48KHz. Попробуйте так: `resample -to 48000 test2.wav | aplay -D hw:1,0`

Comment: с частатой все отлично) ругается на Float 32 bit Little Endian

Comment: А звуковуха не занята пульсой?